# CSV how to find the value, and edit its value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say this is in my CSV file

```
Apple        10
Banana       14
Orange       23
Watermelon   54
```

Lets say, this was last week's supply of fruit in the shop.

So this week, I got 12 Apple, if my fruit number is bigger then previous week, I want to make it so that it replaces 10 with 12. This is my code so far, which puts the data into the csv file.

```
def fruit():
    FruitT = input("Please type in the name of the fruit: ")
    FruitN = input("Please type in the amount of the fruit: ")



    f = open('fruitstcok.csv', 'a')
    f.write(FruitT.title()+','+str(FruitN)+'\n')
    f.close()
    print ("Success")
    fruit()

fruit()
```

How can I make it so that, when I type in the fruit name and its amount, it checks if the amount is bigger, and if it is, it replaces, and if not it doesn't do anything?

Also, I would like to know how you can add the amount to your csv like this.

```
Apple    10,12
```

So later on in the month, I can find out what was the average number of the fruit in the month, by adding all of them and dividing by the number of numbers in the list. I could use len right?

I will create two csv file of course. So far, I know how to read through the csv file and print them.

Comment: You would be better off storing the info in a dict and either pickling or using json

Comment: how would I do that? Sorry, I relatively new to python

Comment: I presume you create the csv originally to store the items ?

Comment: If you want to work with CSV try out the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes I created them so that I can just add the fruit name and its stock, now I want to expend it further. It would be nice if someone could give me a tip on this.

Comment: @Pulimon I can't really understand it, I checked the website.

Comment: @Wdoctor123. I will add an example of how to use pickle. How you originally add the data you will have to adjust for yourself

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I hope you are using csv. I will like csv compare to other storing files. It is just neat.

Comment: @Wdoctor123.  no, I was going to use pickle, it is a lot easier do what you want using it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it is just that, previously, people told me to move to CSV, and now it seems like I have to learn pickle as well

Comment: trust me if you want to persist items and do lookups pickling a dict will be easy, run the  code a couple of times and see what you think

Comment: @PadraicCunningham show me your magic :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pickle:

```
import pickle

def fruit():
        try:
            with open('fruits.pickle', 'rb') as f:
                items = pickle.load(f)
        except (ValueError,IOError) as e:
            print(e)
            items =  {'Banana': {'mon': [14], 'count': 14}, 'Apple': {'mon': [10], 'count': 10}, 'Orange': {'mon': [23], 'count': 23}, 'Watermelon': {'mon': [54], 'count': 54}}
        fruit_t = input("Please type in the name of the fruit: ")
        fruit_n = int(input("Please type in the amount of the fruit: "))
        if fruit_t in items:
            items[fruit_t]["mon"].append(fruit_n)
            if items[fruit_t]["count"] < fruit_n:
                items[fruit_t]["count"] = fruit_n
        else: # else add new fruit
            items[fruit_t] = {"mon":[fruit_n],"count":fruit_n}
        with open('fruits.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(items, f)
        print(items)
```

Like I said in a comment, how you originally create the items and the values they have should be the default value for the first run.

You should also handle the cases where the user inputs an invalid item or does not enter a valid value that can be cast to an int.

It would also be better strong the dicts keys in lowercase and using `fruit_t.lower()`.

To print the information:

```
for k in items:
     print("{} monthly  {}".format(k,items[k]["mon"]))
     print("{} total {}".format(k,items[k]["count"]))
```

Comment: Please type in the name of the fruit: AppleFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fruits.pickle'  is .pickle right file? I saw people using txt file for it

Comment: I added a way to keep track of the total month count, you will need to reset it per month etc.. There should be no error as `a` will create the file if it does not exist

Comment: can you add in the      if fruit_t not in items:items[fruit_t] = fruit_n      I can use validate methods such as .isdigit or .isalpha to make sure. I just tried to add it my self but it won't stay in the dictionary. when I type in another fruit after, it disappears

Comment: new code prints this.    {'Apple': {'count': 10, 'mon': 10}, 'Orange': {'count': 23, 'mon': 23}, 'Banana': {'count': 14, 'mon': 14}, 'Watermelon': {'count': 54, 'mon': 54}}

Comment: yes,  that is the default first run values, really in a realistic situation you would set the values when you intake the stock at the start of the month, that part of the logic only you can decide. Try adding  making sure to use the correct case because as I mentioned the keys are capitalised which really should be change to lowercase

Comment: I'm really sorry for keep on asking. But month was just example. What i would like it that, number keeps on adding to the dictionary like this, 12, 14, 15, 11, 4, 13. and i would just like to find the average of it when I press the average, without altering the file. I will create second file for this so that it doesn't interrupt with other file

Comment: then just make mon's value a list and append instead of +=

Comment: You should also use a try/except as in one of your other questions not isdigit

Comment: how do I make mon's value a list? I'm really sorry... for keep on asking

Comment: change all the subdicts to `{"mon":[],"count":14}` and use append instead of += `items[fruit_t]["mon"] .append(fruit_n)` and `items[fruit_n] = {"mon":[fruit_n],"count":fruit_n}`

Comment: Also, how do I add things to dictionary and stop it printing those brackets and commas etc?

Comment: you need to read the documentation of dicts, you need to iterate over the dict. there is a simple tutorial here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: wow, thank you so much Padraic again. You really taught me alot today. 1hour and 30 minute was really worth awhile. Thank you so much

Comment: I read the whole thing, I understood the whole page, but i can't find out how to print it like this. when i press  (i will add this)  i want it to print Apple 15   Orage 13 etc all in new line also with just normal values

Comment: if fruit_t not in items:items[fruit_t] = fruit_n i put this command in the code, but it only shows for first time, and the data erases next time i print something. I don't think it adds permanently

Comment: It does stay, if the key exists you would never reach that line so you are making a mistake somewhere it should also be `items[fruit_n] = {"mon":fruit_n,"count":fruit_n}` if you are using the updated items format

Comment: I meant when you are trying to add thins, when you enter new fruit. I'm not sure where to put the code. Also when I use your new print format, it works great but there's an error at the end: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I just checked your new code, and it doesn't seem to add. Please could you test it?

Comment: make sure you delete the pickle file before running the new code

Comment: oh btw, how can i just get the number from the count and mon? I need to divide them so i can get the average :)

Comment: You already know how to get the count, look at the loop I provided! To get an average how do you do it? maybe sum() the num values and divide by the num len()?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have start with a very simple implementation, just to make your application work. As a proof of concept just store it in a simple `dict`.

```
fruits = [{'num': [10], 'type': 'Apple'}, {'num': [14], 'type': 'Banana'}]

def update_fruits(fruit, num):
    for i in fruits:
        if i['type'] == fruit:
            if i['num'] >= num:
                i['num'].insert(0, num)
```

By keeping items in a list will allow you to do computation after:

```
update_fruits('Apple', 12)

print fruits 
# [{'num': [12, 10], 'type': 'Apple'}, {'num': [14], 'type': 'Banana'}]
```

And if you need to access the current value, just get the first item in `num`

Comment: how can you type things inside the dictionary? and what happens if you make a mistake when typing into the dictionary?

Comment: I've provided a function that should take care of "typing inside the dictionary" just pass the parameters and you should be all set. In terms of mistakes, it's something you should take care yourself.  Because only you know the requirements.

Comment: Just access the first item in the list and you will get the current value